# Declare Terraform Variable

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, infrastructure

Cloud Provider : Azure
Can I declare resource group , Virtual network , or subnets in Azure as terraform Variable - Infrastructure as code

without variable :-

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
name     = "example"
location = var.location
}
```

Comment: yes, why not???

Comment: How to do this ? i used in different Configuration, For example , configure Example resource group, and then use it for all the VM's

Comment: just check a vm example of terraform, it does that: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
name     = "${var.prefix}-resources"
location = "westeurope"
}
```